# Pyinstaller import modules for self created module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I've a Main python script that use other script that i've created, they're in the same folder, and this second script need PDFKIT module to run.

I've tried to import PDFKIT through the Main script but it don't work, i've searched into the Pyinstaller doc for it and stackoverflow but same thing.

**EDIT:** Okay i managed to find the error : error creating the pdf : No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "b''"
Any idea to solve it ?

Comment: have you installed pip install pdfkit ?

Comment: Yes it's installed, i edited the problem.

Comment: are you on ubuntu/debian?

Comment: Oh, sorry i've not specified that i'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download from [this](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) site the wkhtmltopdf according to [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit) package . Choose the correct version for your system.

Comment: I know it work fine from my system, but when i use Pyinstalled and make the directory and port it on a different one the error appear.

Comment: that is the expected behaviour as wkhtmltopdf is not installed on the new system

Comment: wkhtmltopdf is binary that needs to download manually  and is not done by the package manager.

Comment: Yes, thank you i forgot that's a binary file and not a wheel that's why i struggled, anyway thanks for the help i found my solution.